# Port mapping with Docker and Play

Tags: docker

When running a Play server inside a Docker container with a port mapping (i.e. port X in the machine maps to port Y in the container), i had to add port X to the list of allowed hosts in `secure.conf` in to make it work.

Why is that? How is the Play server aware of the the world outside its container?

Comment: Port is coming within http request in the host header if it is not the standard 80. So Play may check it.

Comment: There is nothing specific to Play, usual docker port mapping